# CakePHP: is there a way of forcing controller to use a certain model as its default?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, controller

I know this may sound weird, but I might need to tell my controller which model is its own. Is there a way of doing this? I mean something else than just `$uses`.

Answer (score 2):

what do you mean?
$uses IS the way to tell a controller which model is its default model.
so you actually answered your own question there...